# Replacing sheet1 by textbox as log data value to create request files VBA Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

Hi All I have an Excel macro to create a request file. Those request files are create from log data numbers which are listed in Sheet1. There is a replacement process I use here. Data from sheet2 (ColumnA) will replace the letters or strings I have in sheet1 that will left all the integers only and remove all text or strings in a log data numbers.

Example:
If I have H1PL12N0 once the macro executed it will become 12 only and create a request file as `h1p-12.req` with a value of either `D` or `M`. My macro is working. My only concern is instead of using Sheet1 I want to use TextBox.

Therefore no need to key-in or input log data numbers in sheet1 instead I will key-in or input it in a TextBox in my UserForm. I already tried to search same or related issue but I cannot find.

Did try assigning or set Textbox to myDataSheet which is Sheet1 but I got an error telling object required. I'm just new in VBA and trying to make my own macro. Hopefully you can help me , thank you in advance.

[image: snapshot of my excel macro]
heres my code:

```
Private Sub CREATE_REQ_Click()
    Dim myData As String
    Dim myReplaceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim myFind As String
    Dim myReplace1 As String
    Dim myReplace2 As String
    Dim sExportFolder, sFN
    Dim rArticleName As Range
    Dim rDisclaimer As Range
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim oTxt As Object

    If project_list.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a project! Thanks!"
        GoTo a11
    End If
    If combo1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select input ! Thanks!"
        GoTo a11
    End If

    If ListBox1.Text = "" Then
       MsgBox "Please select the Block Name! Thanks!"
        GoTo a11
    End If

    If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Key-in folder address ! Thanks!"
        GoTo a11
    End If

    'Specify name of Data sheet
    Set myData = TextBox2
    Set myReplaceSheet = Sheets("Sheet2")

    myLastRow = myReplaceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For myRow = 2 To myLastRow
        myFind = myReplaceSheet.Cells(myRow, "A")
        myReplace1 = myReplaceSheet.Cells(myRow, "B")

        myDataSheet.Select
        'Range("A2").Select

        On Error Resume Next

        'Do all replacements on column A of data sheet
        Columns("A:A").Replace What:=myFind, Replacement:=myReplace1, 
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, 
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next myRow

    sExportFolder = TextBox1  ' "D:\TEST\REQ_FILES_CREATED_HERE"
    Set oSh = Sheet1
    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    For Each rArticleName In oSh.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
        'Set rDisclaimer = combo1.Value.Select 'rArticleName.Offset(, 1)

        If Not (rArticleName = "" Or rArticleName = "LOG DATA") Then
            'Add .txt to the article name as a file name
            sFN = "-" & rArticleName.Value & ".req"
            Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & ListBox1 & sFN, 2, True)
            oTxt.Write combo1.Value
            oTxt.Close
        End If
    Next

    'Reset error checking
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "REQUEST FILES CREATED!"

a11:

End Sub
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi @Luuklag. As mentioned in the title instead of using sheet1 I want to replace sheet1 by textbox where I key in log number. Whatever operation done in sheet1  should also be done the same in textbox once replaced. Which code should i use and where to put it . because when i try setting Set myDataSheet = TextBox2.Value its not working , error appear. Before Set myDataSheet = Sheet1 . but if you can check my code I already change it to myDataSheet = TextBox2.Value but didn't work.

Comment: Hi All still someone can help me about this? thanks for any help..

Comment: You can't set a textbox as a datasheet. Please read about how to define objects.

Comment: Hi Luuklag i alreay change  Dim myData As worksheet as String  but it doesn't work . I just dont have an idea where to put it and how. thank you.